# Optimize DB connectivity for AngularJS app

Tags: php, sql, angularjs, database, oracle

I have an AngularJS v1 app that connects to Oracle DB and takes the values from it.

At the beginning, each page had just several such values, so the optimization was not in question. But now I have pages, that contain dozens of elements with values taken from DB.

Currently, for each element, the name of the element is passed to PHP file that opens a connection to DB, reads the last value (using rownum and order by time) and returns this value back to AngularJS.

So, as you can imagine, it takes quite a while to display all dozens of values on a page (due to the fact that AngularJS first loads all the values and then displays them all together).

I would like to somehow optimize this connectivity.

The example of a page can be seen at: [NP04 Photon Detectors](http://np04-slow-control.web.cern.ch/np04-slow-control/app/#!/mpodpd)

And the code can be found here: [Github](https://github.com/giosal/np04-slow-control)

The PHP file in question is: app/php-db-conn/elementName.conn.php

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I have updated the code to partly retrieve data using the array, but it seems to me that I'm forming JSON in an incorrect way. Could someone please help me out?

**UPDATE 2**

Managed to make it all work, but now it takes even longer to load than before despite the fact that it transfers less data.

Comment: I just looked into the mpodpd.component.js file and i'm screaming in pain. There is a cool feature in every programming language called loop, you should try it.
The next thing would be that you should only do one request and get all the data not like 150 for every little piece. This is a lot faster.
And last but not least:
I don't know how much you can change but you should consider a websocket for a monitoring system.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. That's my idea as well, to do one request for all the data. But now I wonder, should I declare an array with element names, pass it to PHP and retrieve another array? This is what you mean, right?

Comment: That is correct. This will increase the performance in several ways. First the browser don't need to wait for another request to success or fail. Thus if the first request need 10ms the second need to wait 10ms and with all of your request that will increase the load time. The second improvement is that your server don't get ddosed by your own code. So there is a decrease in network traffic. Last but not least you could get all those sweet data in one Database query instead of hundreds.

Comment: Thanks again. The problem for the query is that I need it obviously for other pages and I need to retrieve one result for each element, so I need to pass element_name to the query one by one, don't I? Otherwise the query will retrun several results.

Comment: Hi, I managed to pass array to PHP, but I still can't figure out how to properly respond with the results. Could you please be so kind to help?

Comment: @MrWook, I have managed to edit both the components and php file. But now it seems as if it takes even longer to load despite the fact that it transfers less data. WHat do you think? I've commited to GitHub as well, could you please check?

Comment: You exceed the URI limit with so many entries for the GET request. 

Also what i meant was that you need to create one query like "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ELEMENT_NAME  IN (ALL_YOUR_NAMES)" 

Your component has still way to much redundance code. The only two things that changes in your names are two numbers. Just use a loop for this

Comment: @MrWook, ok, understood. But now, imagine I did for loop in the component, I'm still passing the same amount of entries. Should I divide it into two requests? But then it looses the whole point of unifying all the entries into one request. And I can't reduce the number of entries, due to the fact that the page has to display all of them. Now, if I do the SQL query like you suggest, how would I take only one row for each element? Wouldn't it display all of them?

Comment: Do you really need to do it on the frontend? Can't you just transfere an object or an array with with the rack, the boards and the channel and mix it with the names on the server side?
For the SQL Query you could use "GROUP BY ELEMENT_NAME" and combine it with "min(VALUE_NUMBER)" or "max(VALUE_NUMBER)" or just "VALUE_NUMBER"

Comment: @MrWook problem here is that I use the php file not only for this component, but for others as well, where the element names have different format. In principle, I can write an if clause, that if elemId contains Rack, Board and Channel, then it should work like you propose and the old way otherwise.

Comment: @MrWook, I did try to use group by, but for my current query, that includes TS, ELEMENT_NAME and VALUE_NUMBER, it says that it's not group by expression. This tool is for monitoring, so I need the last value, not min or max. It does work if I remove VALUE_NUMBER and put max(TS). But I need the value...